# Woo Conditionals on init

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the title above the breadcrumbs. My questions is why WooCommerce Conditionals work better on `template_redirect` but don't work on `init`. For example:

```
/** Woo General Init **/
function woo_general_init() {
    echo ( is_product() ) ? 'True' : 'False';

    if( is_product() ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 11 );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'woo_general_init' );
```

Evaluates to `False` at the top of my document when viewing a single WooCommerce product. On the other-hand, if I change `init` to `template_redirect` the conditional outputs `True`:

```
/** Woo General Init **/
function woo_general_init() {
    echo ( is_product() ) ? 'True' : 'False';

    if( is_product() ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 11 );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_general_init' );
```

Why do I get "False" when hooked into `init` but "True" on `template_redirect`? What's the best hook to run WooCommerce conditional data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action `init` happens too early to know if the current page should display a page. You have to wait at least until `template_redirect`. Reference from "`is_page()` not working from within a plugin" - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/115142/26523